# error-Video submission queued for processing

Tags: drupal, video

in drupal after uploading video in video module,and when viewing preview, this message is coming-
Video submission queued for processing. Please wait: our servers are preparing your video for web displaying.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to say what's wrong from this message without more detail, but an idea :

- Are you sure the module / program *(Probably [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/))* that's needed to generate the preview is correctly installed ?
- Did you configure the module properly ?

  - see [Configuring Video Module](http://video.heidisoft.com/content/configuring-video-module), for instance, which gives some details about ffmpeg

Something that might help you is to navigate through the bugtracker for that module, searching for bug-reports that might relate to the kind of problem you are experiencing.

Something like searching for "*processing*" on the bugtracker of the ["video" module](http://drupal.org/project/video), for instance, might be helpful : [Issues for video - processing](http://drupal.org/project/issues/video?text=processing&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All)